# Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Person' when using decorator

Tags: typescript, decorator, tsc, typescript-decorator, typescript-class

I know this seems duplicated but I haven't found a solution to this specific problem (with decorator)
I'm using the *DefaultParameterValue* to add a default parameter to a class:

```
function DefaultParameterValue<T extends { new(...args: any[]): {} }>(constructor: T) {
    return class extends constructor {
        id: number = 123;
    }
}

@DefaultParameterValue
class Person{
    name
    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name
    }
}
const sam = new Person("Sam")
console.log(sam.id)
```

This is giving me an error:

```
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Person'.
```

I don't know if this makes a difference, but I'm my tsconfig.json is like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",   
    "experimentalDecorators": true,                   
    "module": "commonjs",                               
    "rootDir": "./src", 
    "skipLibCheck": true                                
  }
}
```

- Changing the target on tsconfig.json isn't working
- The code works properly and the javascript return to me the id *123*, but the error is still there
- This is my first time trying TypeScript and the first time understanding a decorator
- *tsc* version: 5.0.3

How can I remove the error?

Comment: This behaviour is explicitly called out in the example in [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators): _"Note that the decorator **does not** change the TypeScript type and so the new property ... is not known to the type system"_

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps but it looks like its a matter of declaring the type expected for `same`

```
 const sam: Record<string, any> = new Person("Sam");
 console.log(same.id);
```

folow this link and click run and it should work
example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?declaration=false&experimentalDecorators=true&target=1&module=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEQKbAIYgDZQAoYBOGAtqlKoQGobYioA8AKoqgB4VgAmAzogN6IwqAO4AKAHRSiAcx4AuRBjABPANoBdAJSL+AX0R6AfGIgIeUQiGhxCiploEAoRK8SFyIQkgjYMPPnZOXkQzMAsrG0JnN1jEGC5FMBASACNKRABeRABGACYAZgBuFzc9J3KnAAE0TBx8IlJySho6VCdffz48Sh4EflLXMCbB0PNLayhbMWGyRQiYMBlHAbi3KAALGB4JWdQsoRHY8vKwi0QeUkUAJVQzQi4GBaWAGiVVIwPhEUQewj6wGIAEQAZVIQK0HXMcGwqAk2DgMjElxIEgSkNcQA